Need a good pattern for mapping entities between two data sources
I'm stuck with a very simple problem I can't find a simple solution to. I am looking for an elegant pattern to map data between two datasource
SourceA   SourceB
ClassA1 -> ClassB1
ClassA2 -> ClassB2
ClassA3 -> ClassB3
etc.
I have some static class with overloaded methods mapping data beetween the classes:
public static class Mapper{

    public static ClassB1 Map(ClassA1){
        return new ClassB1();
    }
  
    public static ClassB2 Map(ClassA2){
        return new ClassB2();
    }

    // etc.
}

I want some simple pattern to work in generic-style, like

public void ProcessEntity<TA, TB>(string EntityNameInSourceA, string EntityNameInSourceB){
    List<TA> dataA = Source1.GetData<TA>(EntityNameInSourceA);
    List<TB> dataB = Mapper.Map(dataA);
    Source2.SaveData<TB>(dataB);
}

and use it
public void Main(){
    ProcessEntity<ClassA1, ClassB1>("TableA1", "TableB1");
    ProcessEntity<ClassA2, ClassB2>("TableA2", "TableB2");
    ProcessEntity<ClassA3, ClassB3>("TableA3", "TableB3");
}

so that I could simply add a new pair of classes by modifying Mapper class and adding a new line
ProcessEntity<ClassA4, ClassB4>("TableA4", "TableB4");

The problem is that I can not use this Mapper.Map in generic method because it requires the classes to be specifies at compile time.
Well, I can

Use AutoMapper library
Use if statement to define types beforehand (didn't check it works this way)

if (typeof(TA) == typeof(ClassA1)){
    ClassB1 dataB = Mapper.Map(dataA)
}


Use Adapter pattern, which looks heavy-weight to me in this case

Nevertheless I believe I'm doing something wrong from the beginning and some beautiful solution exists. Any ideas?

because it requires the classes to be specifies at compile time To use a generic method, its generic arguments  also need to be known at compile time.

Are ClassA1, ClassB1 under your control? (ie can you change them)

There is a non generic Map overload that just takes Types.

@tolanj Yes, I can change them, they are basically DTO object now, but I can add properties/methods to them or iherit them from class/interface without problem

Note your example is mixing-up single instances and lists of your classes, but since its pseudo-code I am assuming this is just a mistake.
Fundamentally you want 'double dispatch', ie the function chosen to depend on the [runtime] types of 2 arguments.
One way to do this in c# is with dynamic (which is full runtime dispatch). If you cast the parameter of you call to mapper to (dynamic) then the 'choice' of which mapper function to use will be determined at runtime not compile time.
A down side, as anything that uses dynamic if you can get runtime type errors if you forget to add the correct items to mapper.
If you have control of the ClassA1 type items you can implement this via call backs, ie
public interface IMappable<TOutput> //Possible with some type restrictions so you get some ancestor type for you 'B' classes
{
    TOutput Map();
}

public interface ISaveable //Possible with some type restrictions so you get some ancestor type for you 'B' classes
{
    public void SaveTo(Source Source);
}

public static class Mapper{ //You can move this logic directly INTO A if appropriate

    public static ClassB1 Map(ClassA1 from){
        return new ClassB1();
    }
  
    public static ClassB2 Map(ClassA2 from){
        return new ClassB2();
    }
}

public class ClassB1 : ISaveable { public void SaveTo(Source source) { source.SaveData(this); } }
public class ClassB2 : ISaveable { public void SaveTo(Source source) { source.SaveData(this); } }

public class ClassA1 : IMappable<ClassB1> //This is your fundemental type mapping
{
    public ClassB1 Map() => Mapper.Map(this);
}

public class ClassA2 : IMappable<ClassB2> //This is your fundemental type mapping
{
    public ClassB2 Map() => Mapper.Map(this);
}

And you caller looks something like (ignoring you list stuff for now):
void ProcessEntity<TA>(string EntityNameInSourceA, string EntityNameInSourceB) where TA: IMappable<ISaveable>
{
    TA dataA = Source1.GetData<TA>(EntityNameInSourceA);
    ISaveable dataB = dataA.Map();
    dataB.SaveTo(Source2);
}

WHY?
Well essential the language allows 'single dispatch', you can make a subclass and override a method, so you can change the behavior (the chosen function) depending on 1 [runtime] type only.  By having this class MAKE the second call you get another point which allows an override, which allows double dispatch.

Your example also never uses, passes EntityNameInSourceB so neither does mine, but hopeully its clear where it should go.

Thank you very much for your answer
I inclined to adapter pattern as the best solution and you gave a clear example of the implementation for my case!
Indeed the part saving data should be like
Source2.SaveData(dataB, EntityNameInSourceB);
